# Grunt run curl on changed file only

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to upload a file to a server on change using grunt-run and curl. I can get it to work if I hard code the file name into the actual task, but I'm trying to run it based on the file that changed...here's my grunt file so far (stripped down to the parts related to this question).

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var config = require('./config.json');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        watch: {              
            less : {
                files : ['front-end/less/**/*.less'],
                tasks : ['newer:less','sync:css','run:deploy_less_files']
            }, 
        },

        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ['front-end/_builds/css'],
                    sourceMap : true,                    
                },
                files: [{                
                    cwd: "front-end/less",
                    expand : true,
                    src : [ '**/*.less', '!_settings.less'],
                    dest : "front-end/_builds/css",
                    ext: ".css"
                }]
            },
        },

        sync : {
            target: {},
            css : {
                expand: true,
                flatten :true,
                verbose: true,
                cwd : "front-end/_builds/css/",
                src : "**/*.css",
                dest : "target/css/"
            },       
        },

        run : {
            deploy_less_files : {}
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
       
   

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        if (target == "less") {
            grunt.config.set('run.deploy_less_files.exec','curl -u ' + config.credentials.user + ':' + config.credentials.pw + ' -T  ' + filepath + ' http://localhost:8080/assets/less/');
            grunt.task.run("run:deploy_less_files");
        }
    });
}
```

Here's what I am trying to do in order:

1. Watch all LESS files in /front-end/less
2. If a file changes, compile it to css and place in front-end/_builds/css directory
3. Sync the contents of front-end/_builds/css with my target/css directory.
4. Upload the file via curl to my localhost.

Ideally, I'd like to just grab the css file from either my target or the _builds directory and upload it to my localhost, but I can sort that out if I can get this part working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [comment](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/65#issuecomment-15063567) in the `grunt-contrib-watch` github repo. Excerpts from it read:

> *"Don't use `grunt.event.on('watch')` to run your tasks."*

and...

> *"The watch event is not intended for running tasks."*

However, you can utilize the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener to configure the `exec` property.

The following gist shows how to meet your requirement:

---

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var config = require('./config.json');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    watch: {              
      less : {
        files : ['front-end/less/**/*.less'],
        tasks : ['newer:less','sync:css'/*,'run:deploy_less_files'*/]
      },

      // 1. Added new target to watch the directory in which the resultant
      //    .css files are saved. Set the `task` to `run:deploy_css_files`.
      //    The `nospawn` option must be set to true.
      generatedCss : {
        files : ['target/css/**/*'],
        tasks : ['run:deploy_css_files'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    },

    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          paths: ['front-end/_builds/css'],
          sourceMap : true,                    
        },
        files: [{                
          cwd: "front-end/less",
          expand : true,
          src : [ '**/*.less', '!_settings.less'],
          dest : "front-end/_builds/css",
          ext: ".css"
        }]
      },
    },

    sync : {
      target: {},
      css : {
        expand: true,
        flatten :true,
        verbose: true,
        cwd : "front-end/_builds/css/",
        src : "**/*.css",
        dest : "target/css/"
      },       
    },

    run : {
      deploy_css_files : {// 2. Renamed target and added `exec` key. The
        exec: ''          //    `exec` value is intentionally empty and will
      }                   //    be configured via the `watch` event listener.
    }
  });


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');


  // 3. 'less' and 'sync' targets are aliased before the `watch`
  //    task to ensure the path defined in the `files` property of the
  //    `watch:generatedCss` task exists before `watch`ing.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'sync', 'watch']);

  // 4. Listen for changes via the `watch:generatedCss` target only.
  //    Configures the `exec` property of the `run:deploy_css_files`
  //    target to `curl` the most recently created `.css` file.
  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {

    if (target === 'generatedCss') {
      var cmd = 'curl -u ' + config.credentials.user + ':' +
          config.credentials.pw + ' -T  ' + filepath +
          ' http://localhost:8080/assets/less/';

      grunt.config('run.deploy_css_files.exec', cmd);
    }

  });
}
```

---

**Further explanation**

Firstly, in the `Gruntfile.js` above, you'll notice that `run:deploy_less_files` alias has been omitted from your original `watch.less.tasks` array. Then the following changes were made:

1. Added a new [target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) named `generatedCss` to the `watch` Task. Its `files` value specifies the path to the directory in which the resultant `.css` files are saved. The value in the `task` property array  is set to  `run:deploy_css_files`. The [`nospawn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn) option is set to true.

   **Note** As you mentioned the following in your question:

   > "Ideally, I'd like to just grab the css file from either my target or the _builds directory and upload it to my localhost,.."

   I chose to name the target `generatedCss` and renamed the task to run `deploy_css_files` (instead of `deploy_less_files`) as this better reflects the actual intent.

   The files that ultimately get uploaded via `curl` to your localhost will be from the `target/css/` directory, simply because that's the directory we're watching for changes.
2. Replaced your original `run` task with the following instead:

   ```js
   run : {
     deploy_css_files : {
       exec: ''
     }
   }
   ```

   **Note** The target has been renamed and the `exec` property added. Its value is intentionally empty as this will be configured via the `watch` event listener.
3. `less` and `sync` targets are aliased before the `watch` task of the `default` registered task. This ensures that, (when initially running `grunt` via your CLI), the path defined in the `files` property of the `watch:generatedCss` task exists before `watch`ing begins.
4. Finally, in the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener we listen for changes via the `watch:generatedCss` target only and configure the `exec` property of the `run:deploy_css_files` target to `curl` the most recently created `.css` file.

---

**Running**

When running the `grunt` command via your CLI any changes made to the `.less` files, (i.e. those residing in the `/front-end/less` directory), will trigger the tasks in the correct order (as per your listed points 1-4).

*Caveat: I didn't actually test running the `curl` command, however the file path for the most recent generated `.css` file is assigned to the `filepath` variable in the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener, thus it can be referenced when configuring the `run.deploy_css_files.exec` task/target.*

Note: you'll need to ensure the server supports `POST` requests for your `curl` command to succceed (i.e. it's not something like `SimpleHTTPServer`).

Comment: Wow, this is a lot of useful information, I've been stuck on another task for the past few days so haven't gotten to it yet.  I'll try the implementation this week and get back to you with any feedback - thanks again!

Comment: Finally got to this - worked brilliantly!  Thank you so much - I will use the same methodology for my JS files and any other file I work on locally to move over to my server.